# Tab vs. espaços, para indentação de código

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, indentação

Existe alguma recomendação sobre o que é mais apropriado? Caractere de tabulação (`\t`) ou espaços?

Pelo que vejo, costuma-se ter convenções por linguagem:

- **Ruby**: dois espaços
- **Delphi**: dois espaços
- **Python**: quatro espaços
- **Java**: tabulação
- etc

No caso do Python temos uma particularidade, a indentação é levada em conta pelo compilador, mas ele é inteligente para reconhecer tanto espaços como tabulação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconheço uma recomendação padrão para identação. Cada linguagem usa a sua.

O que eu costumo praticar é seguir a convenção de cada linguagem. Em geral é mais comum usar espaços que tabs.

O que sempre foi uma boa prática pra mim é no começo de um projeto, envolvendo mais de um desenvolvedor, sempre escrever um documento de "code standards" que não só define identação, como também nomes usados em variáveis, métodos, onde usar camelCase, onde usar PascalCase, etc.

A primeira regra desse documento é: para qualquer situação que não se tem algo combinado, combinar.

Pra mim sempre funcionou bem trabalhar desse jeito.